# how to use order by from XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, charts, wpf-controls

I have created a Pie Chart for displaying my RAM utilization (usedRam and availableRam).
I have used `System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting` to create the Pie chart. 
The values for the `usedRam` and `availableRam` are being populated in my database table called `RamUsage`.

I would like to display the latest value `usedRam` and `availableRam` on my Pie Chart.
how to achieve this in XAML ? I cant touch the code behind now, because I have used EntityFramework drag/drop to place the Pie Chart on my View.

XAML for Pie Chart:

```
<dvc:Chart Background="White" Foreground="Black" Name="chart3">
<dvc:PieSeries DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Available}"
  IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Used}" 
  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource serverRamUsagesViewSource}}" />
</dvc:Chart>
```

and the output is

[image: output]

**EDIT**

I would like to display the latest value of the RamUsage from XAML.

for e.g

```
select top 1 [RamID],[Used],[Available] from dbo.RamUsage order by [RamID] desc
```

Comment: Actually what do you want? Your header was saying Order By and content was asking how to display chart ? pls be clear

Comment: @RameshMuthiah _ I would like to display the lastest values of the Ram usage. kindly have a look at my edited question

Answer (score 1):

I've changed DependentValueBinding,IndependentValueBinding to DependentValuePath and IndependentValuePath. Also ensure whether binding is happening correctly. If your binding has no data
then you will not see the results

```
<dvc:PieSeries DependentValuePath="Available" 
        IndependentValuePath="Used" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource serverRamUsagesViewSource}}"  />
```

Comment: Thank you Ramesh, but this is not my question. already my values are being displayed. but I would like to display the latest( top 1 and using oderby ), please see my edited question